# how to sort a list of objects for duplicates

Tags: java

How to sort a list of objects for duplicates in java?basically that every object should be uniqe in list after sorting. Maybe someone knows a good example.

Comment: Do you want to "sort and then remove duplicates" or is simply "removing duplicates" enough? If not, what about "removing duplicates and then sorting"? E.g. is there a particular reason to sort first (or at all) -- if not creating your own duplicate-remover that takes ordering of same-valued items into account? ;-) Please update the title/question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the elements of the List to a Set, and then create a new List with those elements, like this:

```
List<Object> originalList = new ArrayList<Object>();
// the elements of originalList get added here

Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>(originalList);
List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<Object>(set);
```

Be aware that:

- I'm using `Object` as the type for the List and Set, replace it with the appropriate type to suit your needs
- For the above to work correctly, the objects in the list must override both `hashCode` and `equals`
- The elements in the new list will be in different order from those in the original list

Answer (score 2):

To obtain a collection of only the unique elements from a list, you can just add all the elements to a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(l);
```

Comment: What about using the constructor: HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove duplicates, try this:

```
List<Object> l; //Your list of data

for(int i = l.size()-1; i > 0; i--)
  for(int j = i; j > 0; j--)
    if(l.get(i).equals(l.get(j))) //or == for primitives
      l.remove(j);
```

If you have a specific sort you want to apply, you can do it within the same `for` loop after the `if` statement. That's really the only advantage of this over a `HashSet`.

Comment: This doesn't work as written, since when you remove the jth element from the List l, all the higher elements move down and your indices are messed up.  When removing elements using the index, _always work backwards_, e.g. `for(int i = l.size()-1; i >= 0 ; i--)`

Comment: very very very inefficiant, you loop through the set per item of the set, it you have a set of 8 items, that's 8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1 or 36, as you do one less each time), but then say you have 24 items... (298), which increases by the max number each time you add one to the size, not very fast.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, you can use a Set data structure. But since you are looking for a ***sorted*** list, instead of using HashSet, you can go for a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), whose elements are sorted in the natural order by default.

E.g.:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

list.add(8);
list.add(5);
list.add(3);
list.add(5);
list.add(9);

Set<Integer> s = new TreeSet<Integer>(list);

Iterator<Integer> itr = s.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(itr.next() + " ");
}
```

Output:

3 5 8 9

Comment: the reason he wanted it sorted was so the duplicates could be removed easier. however +1 for being the only one who seemed to read the entire op.